# Crash on Windows 7 but running on XP

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, crash

i've written a small application using c++, Qt and Visual Studio 2010. It's working on Windows XP (32bit) but it crashes on Windows 7 (64 bit) right after start-up. I see a "The program has stopped working..." error. Do I have to recompile the application for Windows 7? And is it possible to get more information why it crashes?

Thanks

Comment: Could be anything from a missing DLL to a bug in your code. Add a console to your application, so that Qt has a chance to warn you about what can possibly be wrong. And if you're using Visual Studio, you can probably start your application in the debugger.

Comment: Initially there were some missing DLLs, but I found them using dependency walker. It try with the debugger, but that means I have to install Visual Studio on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you not install the remote debugger?

Comment: You can install with WinDBG or any other debugger. It doesn't have to be visual studio.

Comment: @ Marco, can you elaborate that error? It will be helpful if you specify the full error message content instead of your **...**

Answer (score 1):

In general you wouldn't have to recompile for windows 7, but it depends on your application which you haven't provided details of.

The easiest way to find out is either debug it in windows 7 or put more error handling in, so that it lets you know what has gone wrong, or where it has gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what martiert said, also, if you are using some external elements, images. sound files, video files, etc ... be sure of the file location asd this was a problem for me when I was presenting my graduation project, I moved the whole solution from a directory to another and it crashed because it was reading a not found directory ... so be sure of the links of the images, videos, sounds etc ...

Answer (score -2):

You might have to recompile for Windows 7/64bit. It might not even work after a recompile, since Windows 7 is not XP, and a program written for 32 bit might not work for 64. Often one don't have to recompile, but sometimes one have to, and some times a program which works on XP won't work on Windows 7.

Comment: @Frank Bollack: I dissagree. My answer clearly states that one might not be able to run a program made for xp in win 7. It also states that one might not be able to run a 32bit program in a 64bit OS. Which answer Marco's question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, it doesn't answer any aspect of the question. To make it a useful answer, you could state some of the circumstances that would make the OPs app crash on Win7 or when a recompilation is needed.